# Error parsing JSON Android-Facebook

Tags: android, json, facebook

I'm trying to get my own profile picture from Facebook using Android app.
I use the following code:

```
private void getProfilePicture()
    {       
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putBoolean("redirect", false);
        params.putString("height", "200");
        params.putString("type", "normal");
        params.putString("width", "200");
        /* make the API call */
        new Request(
            Session.getActiveSession(), "/me/picture", params, HttpMethod.GET,
            new Request.Callback()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response)
                {
                    GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                    if (graphObject != null)
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
                        try
                        {
                            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }               
                }
            }
        ).executeAsync();
    }
```

In the line `JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");` an Exception is thrown:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {"url":"https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/hprofile-ak-xaf1\/v\/t1.0-1\/p200x200\/10420230_10153002205624265_4544638089958429298_n.jpg?oh=e82661d538bff26e9b529024329f9c42&oe=55948B63&__gda__=1435630072_674d75534e2151dcac7de09da7b03062","is_silhouette":false,"width":200,"height":200} at data of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

This is the `jsonObject`:

```
{"data":{"url":"https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/hprofile-ak-xaf1\/v\/t1.0-1\/p200x200\/10420230_10153002205624265_4544638089958429298_n.jpg?oh=e82661d538bff26e9b529024329f9c42&oe=55948B63&__gda__=1435630072_674d75534e2151dcac7de09da7b03062","is_silhouette":false,"width":200,"height":200}}
```

What am I doing wrong??
Is there a chance that there's an error with the URL? Because if I try:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("url", "https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/hprofile-ak-xaf1\/v\/t1.0-1\/p200x200\/10420230_10153002205624265_4544638089958429298_n.jpg?oh=e82661d538bff26e9b529024329f9c42&oe=55948B63&__gda__=1435630072_674d75534e2151dcac7de09da7b03062");
```

I get an error: `Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )`
But this is what I get in the response and I can't change it.

Comment: Have you tried URLEncoding it?

Comment: I have jsonObject and It got more data... I can't access the url without parsing the Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object "data" in your json is not an array.
Instead of using:

```
JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
```

try:

```
JSONObject jsonDataObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
```